# How to convert from char * to "WTF::String"?

Tags: c++, webkit

I know how to convert from `WTF::String` to `char *` using `utf8().data()`, but I do not know how to do the reverse.

Answer (score 1):

Use one of the constructors for `WTF::String` for exactly this purpose:

```
WTF::String foo(bar);   // Assuming `bar` is a char*
```

Here are the basic constructors (source: [GitHub](https://github.com/adobe/webkit/blob/master/Source/WTF/wtf/text/WTFString.h))

```
// Construct a string with UTF-16 data, from a null-terminated source.
WTF_EXPORT_STRING_API String(const UChar*);

// Construct a string with latin1 data.
WTF_EXPORT_STRING_API String(const LChar* characters, unsigned length);
WTF_EXPORT_STRING_API String(const char* characters, unsigned length);

// Construct a string with latin1 data, from a null-terminated source.
WTF_EXPORT_STRING_API String(const LChar* characters);
WTF_EXPORT_STRING_API String(const char* characters);
```

Comment: There also appears to be `fromUTF8`, which seems to me like more of a reverse of `utf8().data()`.